# Php - ЧПУ c htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Есть вордпрес с htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Установлен модуль i18n отрабатывающий язык с поддоменом en.
Теперь я зарегистрировал домен com и назначил его алиасом основному сайту и хочу с помощью mod_rewrite получить en язык на com домене.

Примерно так, но почему-то не выходит:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://en.site.ru/$1/ [L]
```

Спасибо за советы.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://en.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем начальный слэш тут?

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://en.site.ru/$1/ [L]
```

У вас запрос постоянно со слэшем?